# passport-facebook Failed to obtain access token

Tags: node.js, express, passport-facebook

I am trying to register my users with Facebook using `passport-facebook@1.0.3` following [this example](https://github.com/tutsplus/passport-social.git). My problem is that when the user is authenticated the response is:

> **Failed to obtain access token**
>
> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND at
>   Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError
>   /home/sigfried/github/passport-social/node_modules/passport-facebook/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:348:17)

I've checked my Express routes and everything seems to be fine. I checked the Network methods with Firefox and when the response come back to my server I've noticed an **500 Internal Server Error** with this address: `http://localhost:3000/login/facebook/callback?code=L4rg3H4sh#_=_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely I was trying to access an `address` in my `localhost`, so I think that the solution here would be to expose, with something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), my local server and then *problem solved*.

Hope this helps someone in a hurry or as *naive* as I was.

Answer (score 0):

check whether your ssl connection is blocking this..

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error on my localhost. After research I found the issue - it didn't work with my node.js (I had v18.12) after upgrade node.js to v19 it was fixed. Hope it helps